# Sublimevideo(html5 видеплеер) ожидание видео

Tags: html5, браузер, видео

В общем на странице вывел sublimeVideo плеер в который передел видео. Видео весит 150МБ. Проблема в том что у кого-то браузер не ждет полной загрузки видео и проигрывает по мере загрузки. А у кого-то ждет полной загрузки видео и только потом начинается воспроизводится. Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема есть в документации плеера.

> Видео не проигрывается, пока полностью не предзагрузится (в режиме
>   flash)

Это, вероятно, вопрос кодирования MP4 видео. Попробуйте перекодировать его при помощи бесплатного приложения  [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) , и убедитесь, что установлен флажок "Web optimized", который позволяет воспроизведение видео (в режиме флэш), ​​даже если оно не загружено полностью.